# file_get_contents Returns empty string, Minecraft API

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to check if a user is premium or not via a php function. I am using the following code, yet the result is "Notch is not valid"

Due to the fact that $auth is just an empty string, for some reason if you go to the url in your browser it will state "true" or "false" but when you use file_get_contents there is no string displayed.

Thank you for the help!

```
<?php
$input = 'Notch';

  function checkPlayer($player) {
    $mcURL = 'http://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=';
    $auth = file_get_contents($mcURL . $player);
if (trim($auth) == "true") {
      echo $player. ' is valid';
    } else {
      echo $player. ' is not valid';
    }
  }

  checkPlayer($input);

?>
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($auth);` this will help you debug the information that is not trimmed from the file. Needs to be immediately after `$auth = file_get_contents($mcURL . $player);`

Comment: Yes check the contents with `var_dump` first. You might have to match it with `1` and `0`

Comment: Ok just tried that and getting "boolean false" which is odd because if you go that URL in your browser it displays true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's an HTTPs URL, Make use of **`cURL`** for this

```
<?php

$input = 'Notch';

function checkPlayer($player) {
$mcURL = 'https://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=';
$mcURL = $mcURL.$player;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $mcURL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); //Add this
$auth = curl_exec($curl);
   if (trim($auth) == "true") {
        echo $player. ' is valid';
    } else {
        echo $player. ' is not valid';
    }
}

checkPlayer($input);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am getting the following output from the code: "Notch is not valid"

Although Notch should be valid, not sure why.

Comment: @user2435125, Can you tell me the output of `var_dump($auth);` after the `$auth = curl_exec($curl);` ? As i don't have `cURL` on my PC. Please post the output.

Comment: Here is the output:

string '<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.2.2</center>
</body>
</html>
' (length=184)
Notch is not valid

Comment: @user2435125, Please check the edited answer. I have added a param.

Answer (score 0):

The http URL does a 301 redirection to the https one. So use the https URL directly in your code and it should work:

```
$mcURL = 'https://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=';
```

Comment: Just tried that code and still not working :/, thank you for the quick response though :)!

I very much appreciate the help in solving this

Comment: @user2435125, there must be something else then. I've just tried this and it works: `var_dump(file_get_contents('https://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=Notch'))`. Try it on your computer too just to be sure it's not some network problem.

Comment: Output: boolean false